# How to add two separate onClick methods to a Dialog using String array to display two options?

Tags: android, android-dialog

```
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case Dialog_alert:

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose any option: ");

        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                setContentView(R.layout.tkentry);

                    // what to do after this..???
```

This is a dialog which asks the user to choose one of the following.
'items' is the String array which has "Update" and "Delete" options.
How to set separate onClick methods for them ?
"Update" and "Delete" are not BUTTONS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two separate `onClick` method. You have to use `int which` to know which item is being selected.

Comment: Yes, and `which` is zero-based, so 0 should be Update and 1 Delete.

Comment: using which as the variable to decide whether "update" or "delete" was selected , is not working! 
i wrote: 
 if( which == 1) { 
...
...
...} 
DOES NOT WORK.

Comment: Try to see what value `which` is returning. Send tle value to `LogCat`. `Log.d(TAG, "which = " + String.valueOf(which);`. Hope you know how to use Logcat, otherwise Google it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what item is selected you must add AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener  listener to your AlertDialog.Builder object.

```
builder.setOnItemSelectedListener (...);
```

You'll be notified when an item is selected so you'll be able to save it and when the confirm button is pressed you can take any action you want depending on the selected option.

Comment: And what argument should be passed inside builder.setOnItemSelectedListener() ?